# Finite moments for norm of $d$-dimensional Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

currently I struggle with the following exercise: Take $n \geq 3$ and take $W_t = (B^1_t,\dots,B^n_t)$ be standard $n$-dimensional Brownian motion started from $x \neq 0$. Considering $Y_t = \|W_t\|^{2-n}$, show that

1. $(Y_t)$ is a local martingale.
2. Find all $p > 0$ such that $E[Y^p_t] < \infty$.

The first exercise I solved using Ito's formula, more precisely I get
$$
d(Y_t) = (2-n) \sum^n_{j=1} \frac{B^{j}_t}{\|W_t\|^n} dB^{j}_t,
$$
so in particular there is no finite variation part. For the second exercise I don't know where to start, one can upgrade the previous result to show even that $(Y_t)$ is a supermartingale but this doesnt seem to be helpful, in particular it seems one needs a statement with Brownian motion.

**Full solution for second part**

Getting started we observe that one has
$$
Y^p_t = \left(\sqrt{(B^{1}_t)^2+\dots+(B^{n}_{t})^2}\right)^{p(2-n)},
$$
using that $(B^{(j)}_t)^{n}_{j=1}$ are independent denote by $Z_t = (B^{1}_t)^2+\dots+(B^{n}_{t})^2$ then since $B_t \sim t N(0,1)$ we just need to find the values of $p > 0$ such that
$$
E[Y^p] = E[Z^{p((2-n)/2)}] \leq C < \infty.
$$
Since $Z \sim \chi^2(n)$ we are going to use the following lemma, which we proof afterwards.

> Let $X \sim \chi^2(k)$ be a qui-squared random variable of degree $k$ if $m > -k/2$ then $E[X^m]$ is finite and is equal too
> $$
> E[X^m] = \frac{2^m \Gamma(k/2+m)}{\Gamma(k/2)}.
> $$

Using the lemma above now can conclude that $E[Y^p]$ is finite iff $p((2-n)/2) > -n/2$ iff $p < \frac{n}{n-2}$ (observe that in the exercise one has $n \geq 0$) and this finishes the proof.

**Proof of the Lemma**: Recall that if $X \sim \chi^2(k)$ then it's density is given by
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} x^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2},
$$
then by direct definition of expected value one has
$$
E[X^m] = \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} x^{k/2+m-1} e^{-x/2} dx,
$$
where after substituting $u = x/2$ with $2du = dx$ one has
$$
E[X^m] = \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{2^m}{\Gamma(k/2)} e^{-u} u^{k/2+m-1} du, 
$$
and using $e^{-u} \geq 1$ for $u \in [0,\infty)$ one concludes that the above is finite if $m > -k/2$ and using the definition of the Gamma function this finishes the proof.

Comment: Do you have the solution? I sketched it as $p<(n+2)/(n-2)$ but I am not sure.

Comment: Using Gerard Letac's comment we know that $\|Z\|^2$ is Chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. I believe it can be checked that if $Y$ is Chi-squared with $n$ degrees of freedom then $E[Y^m]$ exists if $m>-n/2$, hence plugging in $m = -p(n-2)/2$ gives that $p \leq n/(n-2)$, what was your approach?

Comment: almost good, since the inequality should be strict.

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent I used a similar approach with the *inverse* $\chi^2$-squared distribution, but some details escaped me. If (any of) you post a complete answer I'll be glad to check it out, especially on the condition of existence of moments.

Comment: Yes indeed Gerard, and I am going to edit this version later, probably tmr @Snoop but thank you very much I was thinking way to complicated :)

Comment: @Snoop The changes are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second question has nothing to do with the first, since $W_t\sim tZ$, where $Z\sim N(0,I_n)$ You have just to find for which values of $p$ you have $E((\|Z\|^2)^{-p(n-2)/2}) <\infty$, knowing that $\|Z\|^2$ has a Chi square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.