# Is the norm of $n$-dimensional Brownian motion to some power a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory

Currently I am asking myself the following question:

**Setup**:

Suppose that Take $n \geq 3$ and take $W_t = (B^1_t,\dots,B^n_t)$ be standard $n$-dimensional Brownian motion started from $x \neq 0$. Considering $Y_t = \|W_t\|^{2-n}$, I already showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745847/finite-moments-for-norm-of-d-dimensional-brownian-motion) the following two facts:

1. The stochastic process $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a local martingale.
2. The moments $E[Y^p]$ are finite if $p \leq \frac{n}{n-2}$,

**Question**: Can we show that $\lim_{t \to \infty} E[Y_t] = 0$? Is $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ not only a local martingale but a martingale?

**My try**: It was given as a hint that it sufficies to prove that $\lim_{t \to \infty} E[Y_t \mid \|W_t\| \leq R] = 0$ for any fixed $R >0$. Indeed, for every $t \geq 0$ one has by the power property that
$$
E[Y_t] = E(E[Y_t \mid \|W_t\| \leq R]),
$$
hence using the above since $Y_t$ is a positive random variable one has by Fatou's lemma
$$
0 \leq \limsup_{t \to \infty} E[Y_t] \leq E(\limsup_{t \to \infty} E[Y_t \mid \|W_t\| \leq R]) = 0,
$$
and this proves that $\lim_{t \to \infty} E[Y_t] = 0$ and so it is left to verify $\lim_{t \to \infty} E[Y_t \mid \|W_t\| \leq R] = 0$. But this seems to be difficult since both the Sigma-Algebra as well as the random variable depend on the limit that is taken.

It should also not be a martingale by optional stopping theorem, indeed suppose $(Y_t)$ is a martingale then take the last stopping time $\tau = \sup \{t \geq 0 : \|W_t\|^{p-2} = R\}$ where $x \neq R$ then this is finite almost surely, since for $n \geq 3$, Brownian motion is transient, hence ost would imply:
$$
R=E[Y_{\tau}] = E[Y_0] = x,
$$
which yields a contradiction.

Comment: If you're interested, Paolo Baldi's _Stochastic Calculus_ proves that $Y_t$ is not a martingale in Example 8.10.